# ECONNRESET connection reset by peer Kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm having this error in my Application Insight on Azure:

> Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.UvException: Error -4077
>   ECONNRESET connection reset by peer

I have read this bug in Github,(https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/388).

What do this exactly mean? It can be for example a problem if the user close the browser during a AJAX call? I'm not using Sockect in my platform.

Can I fix it in any way? I'm using ASP.NET Core RC1.

Comment: well that would explain why the socket was closed. what do you expect the server to do?

Comment: I'm not using sockets... Thanks

Comment: no under the covers, HTTP needs a socket.

Comment: mmm... Do I need to enable websockets in my web app application? Thanks!

Comment: no. all the problem is is that the client hung up the socket. it shouldn't affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

This "error" actually just indicates that the client terminated the connection.  The server (your code) didn't necessarily do anything wrong, so there's no real problem here.  It's like if someone hung up on you while you're on the phone with them.

To continue to the analogy, you might have done something wrong that caused them to hang up (e.g. in the analogy, maybe you were very rude; on your server, maybe you returned bad data, were taking too long to respond, etc).  But without further information, there's no reason to believe this is an error in your code.  It can safely be ignored.  Maybe the user closed the browser tab, lost internet connection, shut down their computer, etc etc.

Any normal application will see this in the logs from time to time.